# trying to charge content of a external url with relative url in java

Tags: java, http, url

I need to load content of a external url in my web application.

I tried it with HttpsUrlConnection and HttpCliente, I forget it but I have problems with relative URL because it doesn´t work.

if my webapp is `http://example1.com` and I try to charge content of `http://external.com`, the relative url of `http://external.com`, `/images/g.jpg` for example, is trying to solve at `http://example1.com/images/g.jpg`.

I´m desperate, I look for google but I find nothing.

I´m sorry for my bad English.

Thank you!!! :-)

P.D: There is my code (in the code is that helios said about change relative url for absolute url, but it doesn´t work...)

codigoHtml has the html code with relative links, it doesn´t work!!

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {      

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.DEFAULT_HOST, new HttpHost("host_to_redirect"));       

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("host_to_redirect/action.do");

        httpPost.addHeader("Location", "host_to_redirect");

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "value"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "value"));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        httpResponse.addHeader("Location", "host_to_redirect");

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine());
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

        if (entity != null) {
            // System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            response.setHeader("Location", "https://prepliberty.tirea.es:8065/pliberty");
            response.addHeader("Location", "https://prepliberty.tirea.es:8065/pliberty");

            String codigoHtml = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            codigoHtml = codigoHtml.replaceAll("plib_script/", "host_to_redirect/plib_script/");            
            codigoHtml = codigoHtml.replaceAll("plib_css/", "host_to_redirect/plib_css/");
            codigoHtml = codigoHtml.replaceAll("plib_images/", "host_to_redirect/plib_images/");

            response.getWriter().write(codigoHtml);
        }   

    }
```

Comment: Could you add sample code to the question to understand what are you trying?

Comment: Use formatting buttons upthere. Code button places 4 spaces before your text. And that means a code block.

Comment: One thing: are the original links, relative links? (if links are absolute then your result will be `oldhost.com/newhost.com/dir` :) If they are, do you need to transform them? the rule of thumb is trying the string replacing in a `main` method, an informal test. Hardcode the text you receive from the external server and make the replace you intend. Output the result. Onle when it works, try into your real app.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is similar to what [mod_rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for Apache does.

It basically has to rewrite the URLs provided. There's no magic bullet. So what I should advise -if the content is not very complex- is to grab the content as an String and make a replacement (or several).

Something like:

```
String html = ...content from URL... //beware of encoding!!! a lot of programmers neglect this!
html = html.replace(OLD_PREFIX, NEW_PREFIX);
// now you can use html
```

OLD_PREFIX could be `http://external.com/` and NEW_PREFIX could be `http://example1.com/`

You can take into account that URLs are always preceded by a double-quote `"` so prefixes could include that starting `"`. Of course... there can be misreplacements...

Comment: And your English is not that bad. At least for writing that question :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Helios!!

I tried it (change url´s) but it still doesn´t work, when i see the source code, the url´s are fine, but it doesn´t work, i think maybe i have to change some header before send the request, i try to look for this, but i find nothing!!


P.D: Thank you for my english :-)

Comment: When you (as a browser client) receive the page... is it well written? I mean: does it contain `<a href="http://thegoodserver.com/page">...`?